# Inverse of a function containing the ceiling function over the natural numbers

Tags: exponential-function, inverse, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am wondering if there exists an inverse function for $\lceil{e^{x}}\rceil$ over the natural numbers. I don't think it is a trivial task to derive an inverse function for a function containing a ceiling or a floor even if you know there is a bijection, and that an inverse function does exist. Am I wrong?

Thanks for any insight...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if we regard $x \mapsto \lceil e^x \rceil$ as a function with codomain its image, it is bijective, and this doesn't depend on whether we include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ or not. For $x \in [0, \infty)$, $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x \geq 1$, and so
$$e^{x + 1} = e^x + \int_x^{x + 1} e^x \, dt \geq e^x + \int_x^{x + 1} \,dt = e^x + 1.$$
In particular, $$\lceil e^{x + 1} \rceil > \lceil e^x \rceil,$$
so the function is injective. In particular it is bijective onto its image and so admits an inverse.

Comment: No I said over the Natural numbers.

Comment: I see---I've rewritten my reply, which shows that there is an inverse.

Comment: One of your functions in the integral is missing.

Comment: The inequality follows from the inequality $e^x \geq 1$ of the integrands given just before.

Comment: (In particular, the integrand is not missing.)

Comment: One of the left/right inverses is $\ln(\lceil x\rceil)$

Answer (score -1):

While that function is injective, it is not surjective, so it can't has an inverse in the common sense.

What it does have is a right inverse, that is, a function $g$ such that $f \circ g = id$, and you can simply define it as $g(x) = y$ such that $f(y) =x$, which is guaranteed existing a unique.

Finding a closed form for that is another thing, and in general it's not possible, in this case I don't know.

Comment: Certainly the function is surjective onto its range, namely $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: 0, 3, ... have no preimages

Comment: Ah, I misread the original post and thought the domain was the set of real numbers. Anyway, conventions differ for whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @miniBill what do you mean in the common sense?

Comment: @Travis I know they do, that's why I have specified 3 too

Comment: @miniBill I didn't say the function I have is bijective, I'm saying that even if you had that it would still be difficult.

Comment: @kolonel that you normally want to define the inverse over the whole codomain

Comment: @miniBill what properties do I lose if I didn't?

Comment: @miniBill I can just restrict the codomain to the image of the function, what is wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, you can restrict it, then you will have a bijection

Comment: @miniBill is the change of the value of the function constant? I mean floor(x+1)-floor(x) = some constant?

Comment: What do you mean?